# Merging User Accounts

Tags: discussion

Are moderators able to merge user accounts? Here's one example of the same user with two accounts (the first one is now dormant) and these are clearly the same person.

https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/26543/macca
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/40886/andrew-mcleod

What happens when accounts are merged? Are points and badge counts also merged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, the user in question would have to request it themselves. However we can contact type community management team and request they do a merge.

Comment: Thanks, the user is keen to merge his accounts, but not sure how to approach this. I have sent you an email from him which perhaps you can forward onto the community team.

Comment: @Eliot did you ever hear back from Andrew on this one?

Comment: No but will follow up with him now.

Comment: @EliotHarper This one is resolved now, right?

Comment: Yes it is, thanks Adrian.

Comment: @EliotHarper Can you please mark as resolved then? Thanks!